# Selecting text with mouse and highlighting the same text with multiple occurences in that div

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, regex

I am trying to code a program in which when i select a text inside a div on mouse up i want to highlight all the occurrence of the selected text in that div what i have done till now

[**Highlights the selected text anywhere in that div**](http://jsfiddle.net/shT8A/3/)

But this works with only static i.e hardcoded words as shown in the demo
like this

```
 var text = $('div').text().replace(/Ipsum/g,"<span class='red'>Ipsum</span>");
```

here Ipsum is hardcorded and it works fine .What i am trying to do is replace ipsum with dynamically selected text which fails.I have added the demo with what i have reached till now and the code is give below
[**Demo getting selected text dynamically on mouseup**](http://jsfiddle.net/shT8A/6/)

### HTML

```
<div id="div">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
 </div>

<input type="button" value="Click to remove highlight" id="id2" />
```

### Jquery

```
$("div").mouseup(function(){
  $(this).after("Mouse button released.");
              var text = "";
    if (window.getSelection) {
        text = window.getSelection().toString();
    } else if (document.selection && document.selection.type != "Control") {
        text = document.selection.createRange().text;
    } var textspan ="<span class='red'>"+text+'</span>';
        var text1 = $('div').text().replace('/'+text+'/g',textspan);
        alert(text);
          alert(textspan);
            alert(text1);
$('div').html(text1);
});





$('#id2').click(
  function(){
      $( "span.red" ).each(function() {
  $( this ).contents().unwrap();

});

    }
);
```

### Css

```
.red {
color: red;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Imran_Bughio/shT8A/8/)**

I am getting the **selected text** value using this function

```
function getSelectionText() {
    var text = "";
    if (window.getSelection) {
        text = window.getSelection().toString();
    } else if (document.selection && document.selection.type != "Control") {
        text = document.selection.createRange().text;
    }
    return text;
}
```

Then i am using using this script to **highlight the text**

```
function thisRespondHightlightText(thisDiv){
    $(thisDiv).on("mouseup", function () {
        var selectedText = getSelectionText();
        var selectedTextRegExp = new RegExp(selectedText,"g");
        var text = $(this).text().replace(selectedTextRegExp, "<span class='red'>" + selectedText + "</span>");
        $(this).html(text);
    });
}
```

Since this is a function you can use it for any **div you want to respond to highlighting**.

```
thisRespondHightlightText(".select--highlight--active");
```

**HTML:**

```
<div class="select--highlight--active">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</div>
```

Comment: @user3127499 let me know if you don't understand any part of the code.

Comment: i dont not know much about regular expression just that /g is global match and i was wondering why concatanation operation was not working with your answer  now i know why it was not working with that piece of code my question was solved

Comment: This will fail when there is duplicate text in a paragraph as your regular expression is searching globally

Comment: @ImranBughio can you help me here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57198387/how-to-highlight-text-and-label-it-on-runtime-using-javascript-and-html

Answer (score 3):

Using [contenteditable](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/contenteditable) and [execCommand](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/execCommand).

```js
onmouseup = (function(){
  document.execCommand("backColor", false, "chartreuse")
  window.getSelection().removeAllRanges()
})
```

```html
<div contenteditable>
In mathematics, extrapolation is the process of estimating, beyond the original observation range, the value of a variable on the basis of its relationship with another variable. It is similar to interpolation, which produces estimates between known observations, but extrapolation is subject to greater uncertainty and a higher risk of producing meaningless results. Extrapolation may also mean extension of a method, assuming similar methods will be applicable. Extrapolation may also apply to human 
</div>
```