# how to highlight text and label it on runtime using javascript and html

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, web

Below is my code. I want to highlight text on `mouseup`. I am new to Web. I have no idea why my code is not working. It is not highlighting any text.

Can someone help me in finding the problem? The code I have written is mostly what I have copied from here and there on web.

Problem 2: once the text is highlighted i want to open a menu on right click from mouse with 4 to 5 options and select one of them to label the highlighted text. Later download the labeled data in `JSON` format.

Firstly, I want to solve my first problem.

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>TEST</title>

  
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <style>
    .red {
      color: red;
    }
    
    ;
  </style>


  <script>
    thisRespondHightlightText(".select--highlight--active");


    function thisRespondHightlightText(thisDiv) {
      $(thisDiv).on("mouseup", function() {
        var selectedText = getSelectionText();
        var selectedTextRegExp = new RegExp(selectedText, "g");
        var text = $(this).text().replace(selectedTextRegExp, "<span class='red'>" + selectedText + "</span>");
        $(this).html(text);
      });
    }

    function getSelectionText() {
      var text = "";
      if (window.getSelection) {
        text = window.getSelection().toString();
      } else if (document.selection && document.selection.type != "Control") {
        text = document.selection.createRange().text;
      }
      return text;
    }
  </script>
</head>

<body>

  <div class="select--highlight--active">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.</div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: are you expecting something like `hoover`

Comment: 1. highlight the text user selects using mouse.
2. Lable the highlighted text, Right click > pop up menu > select value
for now, the code i have shared is for 1, when i run my code it doesn't highlight the text

Comment: @irumzahra please can you look at my answer, when the user selects the text, it's highlighted in red (only the selected text) I assume thats what you wanted

Comment: yes, i have accepted it. It worked !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

change this, Jquery needs to be ready first

```
  $(function() {
        thisRespondHightlightText(".select--highlight--active");
   });
```

Comment: Please can the person who down voted this explain why? it works with the OP's original request

Comment: can you help me with my second problem now ?

Comment: @irumzahra I'll take a look, but really that's a bit of work if you want to open up a new menu on right click

Comment: Lable the highlighted text: Right click > open pop up menu > select value from menu

Comment: e.g "it is a dog"
 I highlight DOG and give it a label 'Animal'
at the end I want to download it in json format
dog: animal
sparrow: bird

Comment: @Rav I have added your code into snippet. Better to develop your code in it.

Comment: if you first get the relevant plugin https://www.sitepoint.com/right-click-context-menu-plugins/  then see how far you get

Comment: @NipunTharuksha Your edit is wrong, you've encapsulated the function within the document.ready, the OP has understood whats required to change the code.

Comment: @NipunTharuksha firstly the definition of approving an edit is 'Approve edits that clearly improve the post' It doesn't improve the post.